# How to update or sync a tree from a sorted array in C

Tags: c

I have one sorted `int` array and one avl tree. Array data is original data set and the tree is formed from the array elements. Need to get the list of elements in a tree which are either missing or extra from the original array and make the tree similar to the array by deleting or adding the element in the tree.

Example 1:

```
    int orig[5] = {10, 20, 25, 30, 40};
    ref_tree = 10, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 50

    Delete from tree: 35, 50
```

Example 2:

```
    int orig[6] = {10, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40};
    ref_tree = 10, 20, 25, 35

    Add to tree : 30, 40
```

NOTE: If the length of arrays and tree node count are the same, then assume both are having same element list.

I tried something like this:

```
'''
if (array_len < node_count) {
    /*Extra element in ref array */
    while(tree_node) {
        //iterate through all nodes of tree
        bool found = false;
        for (int i=0; i<array_len; i++) {
            if (tree_node->data == orig[i]) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found == false) {
            //Data is extra in tree, so delete node to make it similar.
        }
    }

} else {
    /*Missing element from tree */
    for (i=0; i<orig_len; i++) {
        /* Calling tree find api if element is available or not*/ 
        if (find(orig[i], ref_tree) == false) {
            //Element is Missing
            //add that node from tree to make it similar
        }
    }  
}
'''
```

I want to optimize the code here.

1. Instead of doing a find operation every time while finding missing elements, is there anything that can be done to make the code more efficient?
2. Looping for multiple times in case of finding extra elements in the tree, is it possible to merge into a single loop and optimize the code from any other way?
3. Instead of having 'if-else', is it possible to have a common logic that can handle to get the element to be added/deleted from the tree?

Comment: does your code work correctly?  does your code compile cleanly?  If both of those questions have an answer of `yes` then strongly suggest moving this question to `code review` as that is what that web page(s) is for

Comment: Why not just convert the array to a tree. That way you don't need to compare array and tree. And you don't need an AVL tree implementation. Building a tree from an array yields a balanced tree without the need for rotations.

Comment: @user3386109 that depends on how you build the tree given an already sorted input . The naive approach results in essentially a linked list.

Comment: @user3386109,  Here array is an input which I can't modify and tree I formed is for my use inside module. This array may contain 10 millions of elements sometimes. So, I created AVL tree to make find operation quickly.  So linked-list will not be efficient in this case.

Comment: @PDe It was Shawn that was talking about a linked list, not me. Given an array, you can build a perfectly balanced BST faster than you can compare the array to the existing tree. So there's no point in trying to compare the array to the existing tree. Just build a new tree.

Comment: @user3386109 - if I already have 50k elements in array and tree as well and now if 2 or 3 new elements are added into the array.. so it will be costly operation deleting 50k nodes and then add again 50k + 2 nodes.

Comment: @Shawn Array may contain 10 millions of elements sometimes. So, I created AVL tree to make find operation quickly in my module .. So linked-list will not be efficient in this case

Comment: @PDe If you know the 2 or 3 elements that are new without comparing the array to the tree, then you are absolutely right. Just add the elements to the tree. But it's  unclear whether you have that information. The question seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. You've described your proposed solution, but haven't actually described the underlying problem that led you to that solution.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be making the problem harder than it needs to be, at least conceptually.  You have a sorted array, and you have a binary search tree.  An in-order traversal of the tree will visit the nodes in order of the values they hold.  By matching the the node values traversed to the elements of your list, you can detect which values are missing from the tree and which are extra -- even in the presence of multiple elements and / or multiple nodes having the same value, and even if there are the same number of nodes as values.  At each node:

- if we've exhausted the array, then the node is extra, else
- if the current node has the expected value, then it's a match.  We'll expect the next node to have the next value.
- if the current node has a value less than expected then it's extra.  We'll expect the next node to have the current expected value.
- else the current node has a value greater than expected, so a node with the expected value must have been deleted.  We'll then try again with the same node, expecting it to have the next value.

After the traversal is complete, any list elements after the last one matched or considered correspond to deleted nodes.

That's enough to identify the differences, but that approach does not afford updating the tree as you go, because mutating the tree affects traversal order.  You therefore have (at least) these alternatives:

1. when you detect a tree mutation, correct it immediately and then restart from the beginning, or
2. make a list of the mutations as you go, and fix them all after completing the traversal, or, of course,
3. after the traversal, just build a new tree from your array.